# P mosfet or N mosfet

Tags: mosfet

I would like to know exactly when we use P-mosfet and when we use N-mosfet? How to know that the circuit should use which type of mosfet? I'm confused as I'm drawing a converter circuit which involved mosfet. Any help is so appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jippie , Kaz
Thank you so much for the answer.I have edited my post by adding in a picture.I guess is better to provide the drawing so that you guys can help me to judge should it be a N or P mosfet.As I know I should be using N mosfet but then I get some feedback that I should use P mosfet instead.My intention of the circuit is to varying the duty cycle by providing feedback to control output voltage. Apparently I couldn’t get desirable output, I guess one of the big reason is my connection of mosfet and the feedback loop to PIC. I am not sure is that the correct way.help is appreciated=)

Answer (score 3):

First design criterion here is V<sub>GS</sub>, which is the voltage on the transistor's gate with reference to the transistor's source.

- For a P-MOSFET  V<sub>GS</sub> needs to be lower than 0V to make the transistor conduct current;
- For an N-MOSFET  V<sub>GS</sub> needs to be higher than 0V to make the transistor conduct current.

Second design criterion is that you want the internal diode reverse biased:

- For a P-MOSFET V<sub>DS</sub> must be lower than 0V;
- For an N-MOSFET V<sub>DS</sub> must be higher than 0V.

Notice that V<sub>DS</sub> = -V<sub>SD</sub>.

Depending on the architecture of your inverter you want the Source of the transistors

- at the power rail, either VCC or GND, (most likely for an inverter) or
- on the output rail (most likely for an analog amplifier stage).

So you:

- connect a P-MOSFET with its Source to VCC and you pull the Gate voltage to GND and it starts to conduct. Connect the Gate to VCC and it stops conducting
- connect a N-MOSFET with its Source to GND and you pull the Gate voltage to VCC and it starts to conduct. Connect the Gate to GND and it stops conducting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ4yd6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also notice that a MOSFET need a threshold voltage V<sub>GS,TH</sub> on its gate to slightly start conducting, which is usually in the order of several volts. So the higher or lower from the first paragraph is not entirely accurate, but it works getting the picture. The actual voltage to get the MOSFET in saturation is much higher, in practice you want to pull it as high as possible.

There are quite a few gotcha's with MOSFETs, the most important being:

- Its gate capacitance that will slow down the rate of change of the gate that you try to pull up and down;
- Maximum current as written in the datasheet is only under theoretical optimum conditions: http://www.mcmanis.com/chuck/robotics/projects/esc2/FET-power.html
- Check the datasheet if the internal diode is rated for the current in your application, otherwise use an external diode.
- Beware of ringing as a result of the gate capacity and the connecting wires (however short they are). You proabably want to use a small series resistor to dampen the ringing.
- Keep controller to gate and controller to drain connections as short as possible. These are the major factors in speed of switching.
- Use a controller that supports dead time. This means that during switch over both transistors are momentarily cut off, before the other one is driven into saturation.

Check the datasheet of your MOSFET for details.

Answer (score 1):

An N-MOSFET will open its channel when presented with a voltage that is more positive relative to the voltage that keeps the channel closed. A P-MOSFET will open its channel when presented with a voltage that is more negative relative to the voltage that keeps it pinched off. (The exact absolute levels depend on the type of mosfet, of course: enhancement or depletion mode? Plus variance from unit to unit).

So the transistor is chosen based on whichever behavior is more convenient in the circuit. If the circuit provides an inverted activation signal (one that drives low to indicate "on"), then a design around a P-MOSFET is likely called for.

If you have a circuit based on a positive voltage supply and N-channel transistors (or NPN bipolars, for that matter) and you need the same circuit with all the semantics, but on a negative supply with all the voltages reversed, then you can keep essentially the same circuit, but substitute the complementary parts for the transistors: similar P-channel MOSFETS or PNP transistors. In the schematics for some devices that run on a dual-voltage supply, you will find near-mirror-image circuits based on complementary devices. The primary example of this are class B output stages of amplifiers. (At least, "complementary" output stages). For instance an N-MOSFET delivers current for the positive output swing of the output stage, and a very similar P-MOSFET delivers current for the negative output swing.